# Where are the plants needed to put Mo to sleep in Carto?

Tags: carto

I’m currently stuck in chapter 5 of Carto where I have to find some plants to put Mo to sleep:

[image: Screenshot of Mo’s dialogue.]

However, I’ve looked all over my map and can’t seem to find what he’s looking for.

---

Where are the plants needed to put Mo to sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *three* plants you need to collect and they can only be found *after* talking to [Natig](https://carto.fandom.com/wiki/Natig) and her students.

---

###### Triggering the Event

You *must* talk to [Natig](https://carto.fandom.com/wiki/Natig) and her students to trigger the event that enables you to find the plants you need:

[image]

Each of the children reveal a plant's name and location to you; the three plants are:

- Slumber Stalk
- Dozing Daisies
- Whisper Grass

###### Slumber Stalk

After talking to the [Natig](https://carto.fandom.com/wiki/Natig) and her students, opening your map will cause a new map piece to appear near the field [Tuyaa](https://carto.fandom.com/wiki/Tuyaa) tends to; the plant you're looking for here is in the center of that field:

> [image]

###### Dozing Daisies

This is found by making a circular road with the map. Though you can't make the *entire* circle, starting to form one will give you the additional map piece you need. Once back in the game world, the plant is inside of the circle:

> [image]

###### Whisper Grass

This is found by the mouth of the river where it meets the ocean. Like with the dozing daisies, you don't have all the map pieces for this initially. However, moving the map piece containing the river next to the pieces representing the edge of the ocean will cause the map piece you need to appear; the whisper grass can be found on this new map piece:

> [image]